# Trying to format a curl GET into a Python request

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

```bash
curl 'https://roller.urbit.org/v1/roller' --data-raw \
  '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"1337","method":"getPoint","params":{"ship":"~sampel-palnet"}}' \
  | jq '.result.network.keys.life > 0'
```

(I'm aware the jq is querying for boolean), I'm trying to format this curl request into a python.requests format and having no luck (keeps 404ing).  Have tried setting the params dictionary as params, getPoint as method, but not sure how to deal with jsonrpc and id (or whether I've even formatted the others correctly.

Like so.

```py
import requests


planet = {"ship":"~nidsut-tomdun"}

x = requests.get(url = 'https://roller.urbit.org/v1/roller', method="getPlanet", params = planet)

print(x)
```

I'm stuck at the above [which I am sure is wrong] and the python docs dealing with this seem to have an expired cert so don't want to go to the site.  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What page are you trying to load? https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request

Comment: For anyone from the future, I figured it out.

```
import requests
import json

planet = "~sampel-palnet"

payload = json.dumps({
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "method":"getPoint",
    "params": {"ship":planet},
    "id": "1337"
})

print(payload)


x = requests.post(url = 'https://roller.urbit.org/v1/roller', data=payload)

print(x.json())

```

Comment: there are pages like https://curlconverter.com/ which can convert `curl` command to many different languages.

Comment: if you resolved your problem then you could put it as answer below. And you can also accept own answer. This way solution will be more readable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1. Your curl command results in an HTTP POST request, as documented in `curl --help`: `--data-raw <data> HTTP POST data, '@' allowed`. Your Python call produces a GET request. This difference causes the server to respond with a 404 even if the next point is addressed.
2. The call to `requests.get` seems to be formatted wrong. In particular, "method" in the function call refers to the HTTP method (e.g. GET, POST), which is distinct from the REST API function name `getPlanet`. Since you call `requests.get`, it is already set to GET, and can be omitted. To get the right format, simply pass to Python the same string you passed to curl.

Here's the fixed function call:

```
import requests
data = '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"1337","method":"getPoint","params":{"ship":"~sampel-palnet"}}'
response = requests.post('https://roller.urbit.org/v1/roller', data=data) 
print(response)
```

In general, if you cannot reproduce a curl command in Python, https://curlconverter.com/ may help. In your example it produces almost the exact code I show above.